# Does the Nexus 4 battery drain faster if it has no SIM card inserted?

Tags: battery, sim-card, nexus-4

Does the Nexus 4 battery drain faster if it has no SIM card inserted?

Comment: *LOL* The other way round is more likely. My HTC Wildfire lasts about a week without a SIM inserted. With SIM (but mobile data disabled) up to 4-5 days. Drops below 2 days with mobile data then...

Comment: No idea about Nexus 4 try it and see.  I have seen an old Xperia X8 that used considerably more battery with the sim removed which was the opposite of what I expected.